# Shell script check if variable contains spaces

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting. I have a variable containing path to specific file. I want to check if this variable has any spaces in it.

I tried with

```
  if [[ ${VAR} = "${VAR% *}" ]] ; then
      echo "contains spaces"
  else
      echo "doesnot contain spaces"
  fi
```

But it doesn't work. Any help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or

```
case ${VAR} in
  *\ * ) echo "VAR=$VAR has at least one space char" ;;
  * ) echo "VAR=$VAR has no space chars" ;;
esac
```

IHTH

Comment: I believe this is the most POSIX conformant and robust method of all of the answers given so far.  All of the other answers depend on nonstandard extensions (e.g., `[[` or `\s` in a regex).  FYI, if you also need to match variable values containing tabs, you could do `case ${VAR} in *[[:space:]]*) ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Good solution but you need to reverse the conditions. `${VAR% *}` strips up to the last space, so if it is equal to `${VAR}` then there weren't any spaces.

You should escape the first `${VAR}` in `""` as well in case it is empty.

```
if [[ "${VAR}" == "${VAR% *}" ]] ; then
    echo "doesn't contains spaces"
else
    echo "contains spaces"
fi
```

Comment: In a conditional, `=` is equality, not assignment. `==` is a bash extension, `=` is the POSIX-compliant form.

Comment: Right, but the `[[` indicates we are in bash, so we should use the bash style.

Comment: Well, `[[` is also used in the korn shell.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
echo $VAR | grep ".*\s.*" && echo "Space exists" || echo "No space exists"
```